# Rig issue: Animation is acting different in the render and in the viewport

Tags: rendering, animation, rigging

Today I am facing an issue I am not able to find a solution for the first time.

I rigged a character, did a first animation and then I am trying to render it. All is okay except for the render part.

Here is the pose I get from the animation in the viewport:
[image]

And here is what I get from the render part:
[image]

As you can see, the pose in the render is not right, the character is normaly pushing the bloc.

I cannot figure out how to solve this. I tryed with eevee and cycle, to bake the animation, to merge objects, to apply transform and I looked on the internet. But I am still stuck here :)

If anyone has an idea or a solution, I'll take it !

Have an awesome day,

Ash.

Comment: Can you share the blend file?  It's easier to answer questions like this if we can look at the file.

Comment: I think I have found where the issue is from. But I do not understand why there is a difference between the viewport and the render.
It seems that it is due to the driver I set from the FK to match the IK when I'm in IK mode.
It works well in the viewport but strangelly in the render.
I prefer not to share the blend file, sadly. I am not sure I can in fact.